# multiple checkbox value of table store in an array and send the array to flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am introducing checkbox in a table depending on the number of rows in it (inside tbody). now I want to send the checkbox index to flask app route so that the checked box index value is stored in my database. I am able to alert the check box indexes value (0,1,4....) but how to send this array to flask

I have tried this

```
$('#match').on("click", function() {
  var trs = $("input:checked").closest("tr"); //get tr elements of checked inputs
  var indexes = $.map(trs, function(tr) { return $(tr).index(); }); //make an array containing the indexes of these tr elements

  alert(indexes);
});
```

creating a checkbox for the table

```
$("#my_fo_id>tbody>tr").prepend("<input type='checkbox'  id='check_fo' class='checkBoxClass_fo' style='margin-top: 5px;' name='fo_box'/>");
```

button

```
<button id="match" class="button button1" type="submit">Match</button>
```

table code

```
<table class="responsive display fo_data sortable"  width="100%" id = "my_fo_id">
                    <tbody>
                      {% for row in row_data %}
                      <tr >
                          {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}

                          <td >
                            {{ row_ }}                                
                          </td>
                          {% else %}
                          <td >
                            {{row_}}                              
                          </td>

                          {% endfor %}
                      </tr>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
```

checkbox value array and alerting the array

```
$('#match').on("click", function() {
  var trs = $("input:checked").closest("tr"); //get tr elements of checked inputs
  var indexes = $.map(trs, function(tr) { return $(tr).index(); }); //make an array containing the indexes of these tr elements

  alert(indexes);
});
```

I want send the array to flask app route (/Match) so that the array is stored in database

```
@app.route('/Match', methods=['GET','POST'])
def manual():

if request.method == 'POST':
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/C:/Users/patipra/Desktop/rdot_pac/database/test4.db')
    cr = conn.cursor()
    cr.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS match_id")
    cr.execute("CREATE TABLE match_id (ID INTEGER)")
    return render_template('frame_set.html')   
else:        

    return render_template('home.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to update the set of selected rows each time a checkbox is clicked. You can use JSON and AJAX to send the array to Flask.

```
let indexes_json = JSON.stringify(indexes);
$.post('/Match', indexes_json);
```

You will want to deal with the failure case. Then on the other side, unpack the JSON array. Another option would be to construct a URL that looks like '/Match?4&5&8', which you could query with eg `$.get()` and then unpack.